# creating a custom array adapter for a sectioned list view Android

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to create a contacts page which has sections in the list view that displays items in alphabetical order.

currently i have a JSONObject that contains JSONArrays for each letter that contain JSONObjects for each person in the array. it looks similar to this

```
{"Contacts": //JSONObject
  {
    "B"://JSONArray..
    [
        {"ContactName":sdfsdf,"ID":900,"Number":1368349}, 
        {"ContactName":adsdfd,"ID":1900,"Number":136856},  
         {"ContactName":adglkhdofg,"ID":600,"Number":136845}
   ],
  "C":[
         {"ContactName":alkghoi,"ID":900,"image":1368349.jpg},
         {"ContactName":wetete,"ID":1900,"image":136856.jpg}, 
         {"ContactName":dfhtfh,"ID":600,"image":136845.jpg}
     ]
      .....//and so on.. 
      }
}
```

i'm wanting to pass this object into a custom array adapter and have it loop through and create a header for each JSONArray and the put the items under each one. i have looked on google and found there are many ways of doing this but whats the best most memory and processing efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way of doing this is also the most straightforward solution (at least in my mind); which is create a Contact object that holds the information (name, id, number, etc.).  Then when you create the ArrayAdapter pass the JsonObject which you can then parse to an array of Contact objects.  As long are you recycle your row views it should perform quickly and have a relatively small memory footprint.

Eg. recycling:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        //TODO: create or inflate your view here.  it is only null the first time through
    }

    //TODO: Your other view settings (such as setting the name, id, etc. fields)
    return convertView;
}
```